# Emulator not working on Azure Virtual Machine (Windows 10)

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

Downloaded Universal Windows 10 app samples....built the geo-location app and had problems with the emulator:

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: From what I know, an emulator is virtualized environment and you can't have another virtual environment in an Azure Virtual Machine as it already virtualized.

Comment: Great. Thanks......................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator will not work inside an Azure Virtual Machine. The emulator relies on hyper-v and sets up its own VM so you need to run it on your machine locally.

Comment: Very welcome! Can you please mark as answered to close this thread? Thank you!

Comment: Done. Much appreciated.